# What is the general phenomenon taking place here?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

For many cases while calculating the activity of a particular species I find them calculating like this:

$$a=\frac{p_{Mn}}{p^{\circ}_{Mn}}$$

What I really do not understand is what is evaporating into what. A detailed explanation of the topic and quantification of the parameter as activity is most welcome.

[This link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Solutions_and_Mixtures/Nonideal_Solutions/Activities_and_their_Effects_on_Equilibria) very well explains how thermodynamic activities are defined. However what I really do not understand is how the "estimating activity" technique is to be applied. A detailed answer to that is most welcome.

Comment: Have you tried just looking up definitions of thermodynamic activity? That would be a good way to start.

Comment: What is the meaning of "Mn" ? Is it manganese ? Is so, what is manganese doing here ? And what is $p_{Mn}$ ? Is it a pressure ? Which pressure ? Please explain !

Comment: @Maurice Yes Mn is Manganese. What is it doing here..I do not know.Yes that is partial pressure of Manganese.Please explain this.

Comment: Title is vague and moreover there is not a phenomenon taking place.

Answer (score 2):

At low pressures the activity of a gas can usually be related in a straightforward way to its partial pressure as

$$a=p/p^{\circ}$$

Since the activity of a substance present in multiple phases is the same in all of the phases, for a volatile compound it suffices to determine the partial pressure in the gas phase to know its activity in condensed phases. This is how the activity of water in different materials including foodstuffs is usually determined.

For the case of a *non-volatile* solute in a condensed phase things are not so simple. For electrolytes, theories such as Debye-Hückel do a reasonable job of predicting activities at low concentrations, and other theories do better at higher ionic strengths. Electrochemical measurements can provide experimental values of activities. Because ions usually exhibit strong deviations from ideality this field has been studied extensively and even introductory physical chemistry or analytical chemistry textbooks will address it at some length.

One path to determine the activity of a non-volatile non-electrolyte - for which a vapor-pressure measurement is impractical - is to determine the activity of the *solvent* and to invoke the Gibbs-Duhem equation relating the activities of the solute and solvent. This is what is meant in the Libretext:

> The activity coefficient for a nonvolatile, neutral solute is often estimated by non-linear curve fitting, taking into account the molality of the solute and the activity of the solvent (usually its vapor pressure).

Comment: Ok.But tell me somethin can you explain clearly the section on "Estimating Activities."

Comment: @RajorshiKoyal It's difficult to summarize, after all that's the point of the libretext you link to. You use different methods depending on the type of solute. You mention Mn. This is typically an ion in solution. Then you determine the ionic strength of your solution and look up or compute the "activity coefficient" for Mn at that ionic strength and temperature. You multiply the activity coefficient and concentration of Mn to obtain its activity.

Comment: I still cannot get can you get into the chat once?